# Set column in Glsl matrix

Tags: opengl, glsl

How can I change values in a Matrix in Glsl.
I want to change the falues of the nMatrix in the third column.

So far I tried this:

```c
mat4 nMatrix;

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

    nMatrix = uMatrix;
    for (int k = 0; k < 2; k++) {
         //nMatrix[3].xyz = 0.0;
         nMatrix[3][k]= 0.0;
    }
}
```

But I get a compile error:

> Implicit truncation of vector from size 1 to size 3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why are you looping through this three times with an invariant inner-loop?

Regardless, if you want to set a particular column (3rd) in a 4x4 matrix you can do this:

```c
mat4 nMatrix = uMatrix; // Assuming uMatrix is mat4
nMatrix [2]  = vec4 (0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0);
```

GLSL uses column-major matrices when you use array subscript notation. This will let you access the 3rd column of the matrix as a `vec4`. Your array subscript in the original code snippet is off-by-one, and furthermore it is not clear whether `uMatrix` is even the same size matrix as `nMatrix`.